# Measurable function on Ω

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

$M( \Omega, \mathbf{R}^{+})$ is the set of measurable function on $\Omega $.

> let $\mu ( \Omega) < \infty $ and $f \in M( \Omega, \mathbf{R}^{+})$.

**How can I show that?**

> $f$ is integrable function if only if  the series  $ \Sigma_{n = 1}^{\infty} \mu ( E_n)$ is convergence,  so that $E_n = \{  x \in \Omega :  f(x) \geq n \}$.

Comment: You know, it really is impolite of you to ask 28 questions on this site and not accept the answers you recieve...

Answer (score 1):

Let $g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathsf1_{E_n}$ and $h=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathsf1_{E_n}$.

Then $h(x)=g(x)+1$ and $g\leq f\leq h$ so that: $$\int g\;d\mu\leq\int f\;d\mu\leq\int h\;d\mu$$
 or equivalently: $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)\leq\int f\;d\mu\leq\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)+\mu(\Omega)$$

Since $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$ this justifies the conclusion that $$\int f\;d\mu<\infty\iff\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(E_n)<\infty$$

Comment: what do you mean about "$g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathsf1_{E_n}$ "?

Comment: Do you mean $g=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathsf\chi_{E_n}$

Comment: Yes, that is another notation for it.